# Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $(\sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} - 1)^2 = 49 + 20 \sqrt[3]{6}.$ Find $a + b.$

Tags: polynomials, radicals

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $$(\sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} - 1)^2 = 49 + 20 \sqrt[3]{6}.$$ Find $a + b.$

We let $\sqrt[3]a, \sqrt[3]b$ be $x,y,$ respectively. We expand LHS to get $$x^2+y^2+2xy-2x-2y+1=49+20\sqrt[3]6.$$ Now, I'm stuck. Help? Please share a clear solution :).

Comment: Um there is no motivation there + it literally gives you the answer. Can someone share a real solution?

Answer (score 7):

Okay. **Hint**: consider rational and irrational parts separately.
**Solution**:
Consider $(1+x\sqrt[3]{a}+y\sqrt[3]{b})^2$ for some rational $x,\,y$.
If $a$ or $b$ are other than $6$ and $6^2$ we would have $\sqrt[3]{a}$ and $\sqrt[3]{b}$ in the irrational part (as $(1+\color{blue}a+\color{red}b)^2=1+a^2+b^2+\color{blue}{2a}+\color{red}{2b}+2ab$), but we don't. So we search in the form
$$(1+x\sqrt[3]{6}+y\sqrt[3]{6^2})^2=\\
12xy+1+(x^2+2y)6^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{6}(2x+6y^2)=\\
49+20\sqrt[3]{6}$$
$$\begin{cases}
12xy+1=49\\
2x+6y^2=20\\
x^2+2y=0
\end{cases}$$
[$$\begin{cases}
x=-2\\y=-2\end{cases}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12xy%2B1%3D49%2C+2x%2B6y%5E2%3D20%2C+x%5E2%2B2y%3D0)

Comment: very nice method!

Comment: How did the $-1$ inside the square become positive?

Comment: I don't understand why $a,b$ must be of the form $6n^3$ or $6^2n^3$. May I ask you to add further details?

Comment: Yay, I solved using hint! :D

It was 336 by the way.

Comment: @FormulaWriter assume $a$ or $b$ differs from $x\sqrt[3]{6}$ and $y\sqrt[3]{6^2}$ for some rational $x,\,y$, then $-2a$ or $-2b$ appears in the $(a+b-1)^2$ and they have no chance to cancel with other terms, so we should see them in $49+20\sqrt[3]{6}$, but we see only $\sqrt[3]{6}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I still can't see why a cancellation with other terms is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\alpha = \sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} = 1 + \sqrt{49 + 20 \sqrt[3]{6}}$$

We can compute the minimal polynomial of the RHS:

```
(1 + sqrt(49 + 20 * (6)^(1/3))).minpoly()
x^3 - 72*x - 336
```

and then applying Cardano's formula we get $\alpha = 2\cdot (6^{1/3} + 6^{2/3})$.

We can transform this into $a,b$ form with $2^3 = 8$ and $6^2 = 36$:

$$\alpha = \sqrt[3]{48} + \sqrt[3]{288}$$